# TypeScript Error with 'react-on-screen' in a Next.js Project | Not a valid JSX element

Tags: node.js, next.js, yarnpkg, contentful

I'm encountering a TypeScript error when trying to use the `react-on-screen` package in a Next.js project. The error occurs when I run `yarn build`.

```
Type error: 'TrackVisibility' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'TrackVisibility' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/path/to/node_modules/@types/hoist-non-react-statics/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ReactNode'.
        Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

**Steps Taken:**

1. Checked that `react-on-screen` is installed and up-to-date. The package is listed in `package.json` and running `yarn list react-on-screen` confirms it's installed at version 2.1.1, which matches the latest version on npm.
2. Reviewed the usage of `TrackVisibility` in my code and compared it to the example provided in the `react-on-screen` documentation. The usage appears to be correct.
3. Checked for TypeScript definitions in the `react-on-screen` package but didn't find any `.d.ts` files.
4. Deleted yarn.lock & node modules

** Code Snippet:
**
Here's how I'm using `TrackVisibility` in my component:

```
import TrackVisibility from 'react-on-screen';

// ... other imports and code

const InfoHome: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <GridCell className="grid-cell grid-5 grid-md-4 ">
     <TrackVisibility once>
              {({ isVisible }) => (
                <AnimatedBox
                  className={`${isVisible ? 'visible' : 'not-visible'}`}
                >
                  <List className="info-home-list">
                    {items.map(item => (
                      <Item key={item} title={item} />
                    ))}
                  </List>
                  <Description className="info-home-description">
                    We are a full-service trading company. Whether you&apos;re
                    seeking to buy or sell, our mission is the same: from the
                    first call to the last delivery, we&apos;re the partner you
                    trust and depend on.
                  </Description>
                  ...
                </AnimatedBox>
              )}
            </TrackVisibility>
          </GridCell>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any insights would be appreciated.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "tyr-site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^14.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.9",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.4",
    "@types/rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/styled-system": "^5.1.10",
    "contentful": "^7.15.0",
    "next": "^12.0.0",
    "next-react-svg": "1.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-on-screen": "^2.1.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.13",
    "rebass": "^4.0.7",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "styled-reset": "^4.3.1",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.8.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.8.2",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
}
```

This project was built by another developer a few years ago, so looking to make as few changes as possible.

Checked out the package for hints, but all looks well.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-on-screen

I've been having other issues and have resorted to stripping them out for html/css options.

Comment: Regarding point #3, there's an [index.d.ts](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-on-screen/blob/v2.1.1/index.d.ts) file in the package root. Are you sure you installed it correctly?